# wordpress localisation not working

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, wordpress-theming

I have en_US.mo and en_US.po files in themes/languages folder. 
My themes/functions.php are

```
function custom_theme_setup() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    $lang_dir = get_template_directory() . '/languages';                                                                                                                                                   
    $locale = "en_US";  // get_locale() is also returning same                                                                                                                                                                    
    if ( is_readable( "$lang_dir/$locale.mo"))
        echo "Yes, its working";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    echo load_theme_textdomain('tutsplus', $lang_dir);
    _e("Hello\n","tutsplus");
}                                                                                                                                                                    
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup');
_e("Hello\n","tutsplus");
```

I have en_US.po file which contains

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-07-22 18:39+0530\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: en_US\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: getetxt.php:80
#, php-format
msgid "Hello\n"
msgstr "bonjure\n"
```

I have included one file at the end, which also has the same

```
_e("Hello\n", 'tutsplus');
```

but none of this seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native translators in Wordpress does not recognise `"`, so it skips that translation, that is why you don't see the translated text in the front end

You should, and this is a golden rule, **ALWAYS** use the single `'`.  So your string should be

```
_e( 'Hello\n', 'tutsplus');
```

Another point of note. You can drop the text domain completely.

```
 e( 'Hello\n' );
```

If you make use of the text domain, it **must** be the same as the text domain explicitly named in your main stylesheet's header.

Comment: It started working , thanks. I have one more problem. I am setting different language in config file like de_DE, then its not able to set translate although de_DE.mo file exists and its printing "Yes, it working".

Comment: Set function accordingly to changes in wp_config

Comment: I am using same file .mo file with de_DE.mo name. So it shouldn't be problem. Is there any way i can debug why its not picking up translation ?

Comment: load_theme_textdomain returns true if i put WPLANG to en_US and if i set WPLANG to de_DE then returns false. In the language folder , there are de_DE.mo and en_US.mo . Both are same. What can be the error ? I guess after changing WPLANG to de_DE , its still looking for en_US.mo.

Comment: It will return false, because your function is looking for `en_US` from WPLANG.

Comment: But when i am doing echo WPLANG , its showing de_DE.

Comment: Do have have the pot file to create a new de_DE.mo file

Comment: I don't have pot file , i have .po file. Its content is same as i posted in question.